# ClassNotFoundException when using neo4j jdbc driver

Tags: java, jdbc, neo4j

I'm using neo4j-community-2.3.0-M02 and my neo4j jdbc driver 3.0, when I'm creating db connection I got exception `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver`

Here is the method that I used create db connection.

```
private void createDbConnection(){
    System.out.println("Creating neo4j db connection.");
    try {
        Class.forName("org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = (Connection) 
                DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:neo4j:http:/<<ip_address>>:7474/",userName,passWord);
        System.out.println("neo4jConnection:"+connection.toString());
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Is there any mismatching between the above libraries that I used or there any error in my method?

As requested here is full stacktrace,

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1858)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1709)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:195)
at com.springapp.utils.Neo4jUtil.createDbConnection(Neo4jUtil.java:38)
at com.springapp.utils.Neo4jUtil.<init>(Neo4jUtil.java:29)
at com.springapp.utils.Neo4jUtil.<init>(Neo4jUtil.java:15)
at com.springapp.utils.Neo4jUtil$Neo4jHolder.<clinit>(Neo4jUtil.java:60)
at com.springapp.utils.Neo4jUtil.getInstance(Neo4jUtil.java:64)
at com.springapp.controllers.CdrProcessController.getInstance(CdrProcessController.java:208)
at com.springapp.controllers.CdrProcessController.cdrRelationClear(CdrProcessController.java:166)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:175)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:446)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:434)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.springapp</groupId>
<artifactId>Adaptor</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Adaptor</name>

<properties>
    <spring.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>neo4j-public</id>
        <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/content/groups/everything</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--Jackson libs-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-lgpl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-lgpl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--Redis dependencies-->
    <!--Redis 2.7.2 and spring 1.5.1 are not compatible with each other-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
        <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        <!--<version>2.6.2</version>-->
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!---->
    <!-- New redis client for threading-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>biz.paluch.redis</groupId>
        <artifactId>lettuce</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- -->
    <!--MySQL dependencies-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--Access xml data-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>stax</groupId>
        <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!---->

    <!--Read Json-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!---->
    <!-- Apache htttp client-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- -->
    <!-- Json for htttp client-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20151123</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- -->
    <!-- Read csv files-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- -->

    <!-- Neo4j Jdbc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- For file and in-memory support, add these two as well -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>Adaptor</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/config</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Comment: Looks like the jar which contains the class `org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver` is not in the classpath

Comment: @Jens, I don't think so, I adding libraries using maven in a pom.xml file. It correctly shows all the libraries I used.

Comment: Your code does not look like the example here: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc.  My guess is that there is no class org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver.  Open the JAR and see.

Comment: @Hasitha Show your pom please and how you run your program?

Comment: @Jens, Using Controller class I just call createDbConnection() method. I added pom.xml to my question.

Comment: @Hasitha so you run it in a webcontainer? Do your war contain the neo4j Driver class

Comment: @Jens, It contains neo4j jdbc driver 3.0 jar but when I extracted that jar there is no Driver class, what can I do for this?

Comment: add the following dependency: `<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.neo4j.driver/neo4j-java-driver -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j.driver</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.4</version>
</dependency>
`

Comment: if you are using Eclipse , got to your project Right Click > Properties > Deployment Assembly > Add > Java Build Path Entries > Maven Dependencies , in order to export the maven dependencies as well , and then redeploy your app

Comment: @Jens, I add that dependency but still no luck, same exception throws.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed `Class.forName("org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver");` line and added following two lines before creating the connection.

```
Driver driver = new org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver();
DriverManager.registerDriver(driver);
```

I did this after referring [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-db-connections.htm) tutorial. Second approach solved my issue successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Using the URL `jdbc: neo4j: bolt://localhost` for jdbc works for me